# Is it possible to use links in a JQuery Mobile Form Label?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have just encountered a strange problem when using jQuery Mobile.

I have a link inside a form element label - a checkbox label to be exact but the link does not work.

I have tried reading the docs but can't seem to find anything on it.

Here is my markup:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <input type="checkbox" class="cbox" name="OptIn" id="OptIn"/>
        <label for="OptIn">Receive E-mails From Us</label>

       <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="cbox" name="tandc" id="tandc"/>
       <label for="tandc">I agree to the <a href="/tandcs.html" target="_BLANK" >Terms & Conditions</a></label>   
   </fieldset>
</div>
```

When the link is clicked it just toggles the checkbox state.

**UPDATE**

Just realised I can open the link by right clicking but obviously on a mobile device that's not very useful....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this is the correct solution for mobile and non mobile browsers

```
$('.ui-checkbox a').bind("tap click", function( event, data ){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $.mobile.changePage($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: Saved my day, thank you so much! Just a small improvement: one could actually use `this.href` instead of creating a jQuery object with `$(this).attr('href');`.

Comment: @SunilMishra: Missing "http://" in href. But even then it won't work because of same origin policy in JSFiddle, just check the console output of your browser's dev tools.

Comment: @PhilippRieber I even tried with localpage (i.e. using something like #page) but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem and solved it using:

```
$('.ui-btn-text a').click(function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    window.open($this.attr('href'), $this.attr('target'));     
});
```

So if any link within a button-text is clicked it will be opened in a new window. If you want it in the same window just use $.mobile.changePage as Phil showed.

Comment: This solution worked better for me because I needed to open the link in a new window. $.mobile.changePage left the calling page in an abortive transitioning state

Answer (score 3):

I tried the above mentioned solutions on jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 with jQuery 1.7.2 without success.

After a bit of tinkering and reading into the new jQuery event functions I came up with my own solution to make all anchors in labels clickable without loosing jQuery Mobile default behaviour on the rest of the label:

```
jQuery('label').each(function(){
    var e = jQuery(this).data('events');
    jQuery('.agree label').undelegate();
    jQuery('.agree label *:not(a)').delegate(e);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

use on() and off() instead

```
$('label').each(function(){
  var e = $(this).data('events');
  $('label').off();
  $('label').not('a').on(e);
});
```

Comment: This was working better for me : `$('label').each(function(){
       var e = $(this).data('events');
       $(this).off();
       $(this).not('a').on(e);
   });`

Answer (score 2):

There a some improvements that can be made but here is a rough draft:

- http://jsfiddle.net/KADqA/

JS

```
$('.ui-btn-text').click(function(event) {
    var checked = $("#tandc[type='checkbox']").is(":checked");
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.children('a').length) {
        $.mobile.changePage('#tc', {
            transition : 'pop',
            role       : 'dialog'
        });
    }
    stateOfCheckbox(checked);
});

function stateOfCheckbox(checked) {
    $('#home').live( 'pagebeforeshow',function(event){
        $("#tandc[type='checkbox']").attr("checked",checked).checkboxradio("refresh");
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <input type="checkbox" class="cbox" name="OptIn" id="OptIn"/>
            <label for="OptIn">Receive E-mails From Us</label>

           <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="cbox" name="tandc" id="tandc"/>
           <label for="tandc">I agree to the <a href="#tc" data-rel="dialog" >Terms &amp; Conditions</a></label>   
       </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="tc">
    <div data-role="header"> 
        <h1>T and C</h1> 
    </div>
    Read me
</div>​
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also just override the event:

```
 $('.ui-checkbox a').click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
 })
```

Comment: thanks Florian, I will do my best to try this out and get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

On Android the solutions above did not work on Android.

It only works when using on `pagecreate` and without event delegation.

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', function(event, ui) {
    $(".ui-checkbox a").on("click tap", function() {
        $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', this.href);

        return false;
    });
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is posible solution if you want to open the link in a popup.

```
    $('.ui-checkbox a').bind('click tap', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $($(this).attr('href')).popup('open');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Id or class into parent label have a tag
and using script of @alex dms

```
$('#field-contain label a').bind("tap click", function( event, data ){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $.mobile.changePage($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Try it, work perfecly on my mobile and desktop

```
https://jsfiddle.net/vulieumang/p91zhmnp/
```