# jquerymobile clickable link in chechboxes

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, hyperlink

It seems hard to just have a link working inside a checkbox label, overriding the default click event

```
<input type="checkbox" name="pr1" id="checkbox-5a" />
<label for="checkbox-5a">Check3 <a href="http://www.google.com" data-ajax="false" rel="external" style=" z-index:70000;">link</a></label>
```

it probably requires javascript to make it work, and how? thx

http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/M7Bwc/1

**edit**: seems can do it with onclick and location.href

```
<input type="checkbox" name="pr1" id="checkbox-5a" />
<label for="checkbox-5a">Check3 <a onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com'">link</a></label>
```

Comment: With this: `$('a').click(function(e){alert(e.target.href);});` you can see the href attr.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632351/is-it-possible-to-use-links-in-a-jquery-mobile-form-label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('label').click(function(e){ // or $('label a').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
})
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M7Bwc/6/)

Comment: Wouldn't you want to stop propagation on the anchor's click rather than on the label's click?

Comment: @Raminson see this if you have an android device http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646653/android-unclickable-link-inside-a-jqmobile-checkbox-label

Comment: this helped me solve that for android/iphone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632351/is-it-possible-to-use-links-in-a-jquery-mobile-form-label/11728604#11728604

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with putting the link immediately after the label:

```
<label for="checkbox-5a">Check3 </label><a href="http://www.google.com"
       data-ajax="false" rel="external" style=" z-index:70000;">link</a>
```

Or, if you really feel you must subvert the standard label behaviour* why not just use a span instead?

<sub>* Please don't.</sub>

**EDIT:** Fine, try this:

```
$("label a").click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Comment: When you click it you are forwarded?

Comment: When you click what? The link? If you don't put links inside elements that have their own click behaviour you won't have a problem, and you won't confuse your users.

Comment: I think OP needs both of the things. Partial lablel Attached with checkbox and Partial work as link

Comment: @RabNawaz - I would think `$("label a").click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});` would do it, but I still think it's a bad plan to structure the html like that at all...